# An involution but without $(ab)^*=b^*a^*$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Just when looking at the definition of a $*$-algebra, or a Banach $*$ -algebra, we need the involution to verify $(ab)^*=b^*a^*$, so I am wondering what are some examples of involutions ( $(a^*)^*= a$ ) which are not satisfying $(ab)^*=b^*a^*$ in general?

Comment: when you say all the involutions, you mean all involutions must be like the conjugation in $\mathbb{C}= \mathbb{R}\oplus \mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by "this gives all the involutions" ? you mean in $A$ ?